# How to get state from custom hooks to update in "parent" component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to separate some logic from my component into a custom hook. I feel like i'm misunderstanding some fundamentals but I thought my code would work. I basically update my state in my custom `useTrip` hook, and i want my `map` component to have that same updated state.

useTrip.js:

```
export const useTrip = () => {
    const [businesses, setBusinesses] = useState([])
    useEffect(()=>{
        console.log(businesses) //prints expected results
    },[businesses])
    const fetchData = async (name, lat, lng) => {
        const response = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/category/' + lat + "/" + lng + '/' + name)
        const result = await response.json();
        setBusinesses(result)
    }
 return { businesses, fetchData } 
}
```

Map.js (component that uses useTrip):

```
export const Map= (props) => {
    const {businesses} = useTrip()
    return(<>
        {businesses.map((.....)}
    </>)
}
```

Parent.js (parent of map.js):

```
export const Parent= (props) => {
    const {fetchData} = useTrip()
    useEffect(() => {
        fetchData(title, lat, lng)
    }, [origin])
    return(<>
        
    </>)
}
```

The `businesses` is always an empty array when inside the `Map` component. my code was working before i started refactoring. Isnt the updated state in the custom hook suppose to be consistent across the components that use it?

Comment: Where and how you are invoking `fetchData`?

Comment: @user1672994 sorry i made a typo asking the question. ive made edits to the question. I call `fetchData` and use `businesses` state in seperate components.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must use your custom hook on `Parent` component, and send the `businesses` to your `Map` component *via* props.

i.e.

```
function Parent (props) {
  const { fetchData, businesses } = useTrip()

  useEffect(() => {
        fetchData(title, lat, lng)
  }, [origin])

  return (
    <Map businesses={businesses} />
  )
}

function Map (props) {
  const { businesses } = props
  return (
    <>
      {businesses.map(/* ... */)}
    </>
  )
}
```

If you call your custom hook on each component, they will get their own state

Comment: i see. i just want to confirm 1. if i wanted to avoid "prop drilling" would i HAVE to use a global state management (redux) or is there another alternative.  2. is the state created in the custom hook basically an 'instance' that is specific to the component that called it?

Comment: @benwl 1. you could also research about react's `Context` api. 2. maybe "instance" is not accurate, but your toughts are correct: each state created is independent from the other so specific to the component which called the custom hook.

Comment: @benwl It's a perfectly valid pattern to have "container" components which implement _fetching_ logic, and "display" components which implement the rendering logic